# Unable to show Items in RecyclerView with Dynamic Data

Tags: java, android, json, android-recyclerview, adapter

I'm trying to show some data that I fetch from server But I'm unable to show that fetched data in `recyclerView`. Data is valid and parsing (JSON Parsing) working well but my activity shows a white screen only.
When I Run the app with some dummy data app works alright, the problem arrive when I try to set data that I parsed from server.
Here is my MainClass

```
public class JSONDataViewer extends AppCompatActivity {

    Context context;
    //    private List<Movie> movieList
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private CustomAdapter mAdapter;
    private List<MyData> dataList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_jsondata_viewer);
        this.context = this;
        AndroidNetworking.initialize(getApplicationContext());

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
//        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

//        loadDummyData();
        loadData();
        Log.e("DataListPopulated", "Data list populated");
        mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(dataList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        Log.e("SettingAdapter", "Setting Adapter");
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        Log.e("AdapterSet", "Adapter Set Success");
    }

    private void loadDummyData() {

        String question = "Question ";
        int qNo = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            qNo++;
            MyData data = new MyData("" + qNo, question + qNo);
            Log.e("Question" + " " + qNo,
                    "\nQuestion id = " + data.getQuestionId() +
                            " Question text = " + data.getQuestionText());
            dataList.add(data);

        }
    }

    private void loadData() {
        AndroidNetworking.post("http://www.skafs.com/survey/api/index.php")
                .addBodyParameter("tag", "getquestion")
                .addBodyParameter("category_id", "2")
                .setPriority(Priority.MEDIUM)
                .build()
                .getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.i("LoadingData", "" + "Successful" + response);
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Response:\n" + "Loading Data" + response,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        boolean success = response.optBoolean("success");
                        if (success) {
                            Log.e("InsideSuccess", "Success = " + success);
                            try {
                                JSONArray questions =
                                        response.optJSONArray("questions");
                                Log.e("Questions", questions.toString());
                                for (int i = 0; i < questions.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject obj = questions.getJSONObject(i);
                                    MyData data = new MyData(
                                            obj.getString("question_id"),
                                            obj.getString("question_text"));
                                    Log.e("Question" + " " + i,
                                            "\nQuestion id = " + data.getQuestionId() +
                                                    " Question text = " + data.getQuestionText());
                                    dataList.add(data);
                                }
                                Log.e("ListData", "List Size is = "+dataList.size());
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(ANError anError) {
                        anError.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e("ParsingJSON", "" + "Failed getting json");
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

you can see there are two methods the above code `loadDummyData();` and `loadData();` Trying with 1st method there is no issue.
I have some Log statements that shows data from server is valid and dataList has size of 9.
Here is my data form Log

```
10-17 21:25:25.217 3078-3078/hostflippa.com.opencart_android E/InsideSuccess: Success = true
10-17 21:25:25.219 3078-3078/hostflippa.com.opencart_android E/Questions: [{"question_id":"1","question_text":"License Status","question_type":"radio","options":[{"option_id":"1","option_text":"Valid","option_value":"5"},{"option_id":"2","option_text":"Expired","option_value":"0"},{"option_id":"3","option_text":"Without License","option_value":"0"}]},{"question_id":"2","question_text":"License date of validity","question_type":"editText","options":[]},{"question_id":"3","question_text":"Type of License","question_type":"radio","options":[{"option_id":"4","option_text":"A-Category","option_value":"5"},{"option_id":"5","option_text":"B-Category","option_value":"2"},{"option_id":"6","option_text":"C-Category","option_value":"2"},{"option_id":"7","option_text":"Dispensar","option_value":"1"},{"option_id":"457","option_text":"20\/21","option_value":"1"}]},{"question_id":"4","question_text":"License Ownership","question_type":"radio","options":[{"option_id":"8","option_text":"Individual","option_value":"0"},{"option_id":"9","option_text":"Chain Pharmacy","option_value":"0"},{"option_id":"10","option_text":"Company","option_value":"0"}]},{"question_id":"5","question_text":"License Number","question_type":"editText","options":[]},{"question_id":"6","question_text":"Computerized License No","question_type":"editText","options":[]},{"question_id":"7","question_text":"NTN Present","question_type":"checkbox","options":[{"option_id":"11","option_text":"Yes","option_value":"1"},{"option_id":"12","option_text":"No","option_value":"0"}]},{"question_id":"8","question_text":"NTN No.","question_type":"editText","options":[]},{"question_id":"9","question_text":"Visit Type","question_type":"radio","options":[{"option_id":"13","option_text":"First visit","option_value":"0"},{"option_id":"14","option_text":"Second visit","option_value":"0"}]}]
10-17 21:25:25.219 3078-3078/hostflippa.com.opencart_android E/Question 0: Question id = 1 Question text = License Status
10-17 21:25:25.219 3078-3078/hostflippa.com.opencart_android E/Question 1: Question id = 2 Question text = License date of validity
10-17 21:25:25.220 3078-3078/hostflippa.com.opencart_android E/Question 2: Question id = 3 Question text = Type of License
10-17 21:25:25.220 3078-3078/hostflippa.com.opencart_android E/Question 3: Question id = 4 Question text = License Ownership
10-17 21:25:25.220 3078-3078/hostflippa.com.opencart_android E/Question 4: Question id = 5 Question text = License Number
10-17 21:25:25.220 3078-3078/hostflippa.com.opencart_android E/Question 5: Question id = 6 Question text = Computerized License No
10-17 21:25:25.221 3078-3078/hostflippa.com.opencart_android E/Question 6: Question id = 7 Question text = NTN Present
10-17 21:25:25.221 3078-3078/hostflippa.com.opencart_android E/Question 7: Question id = 8 Question text = NTN No.
10-17 21:25:25.221 3078-3078/hostflippa.com.opencart_android E/Question 8: Question id = 9 Question text = Visit Type
10-17 21:25:25.221 3078-3078/hostflippa.com.opencart_android E/ListData: List Size is = 9
```

Please point me to the direction where I'm doing something wrong.

**I'm** not getting any exception. Here is my `CustomAdapter` class

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<MyData> dataList;

    public CustomAdapter(List<MyData> dataList) {
        this.dataList = dataList;
        Log.e("Constructor", "Working");
        Log.e("Constructor", "DataList Size = " + dataList.size());
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.card_lay, parent, false);
        Log.e("LayoutInflated", "Working");

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.e("OnBIndMethod", "OnBind Working");
        MyData data = dataList.get(position);
        holder.questionId.setText(data.getQuestionId());
        holder.questionText.setText(data.getQuestionText());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataList.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView questionId, questionText;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            questionId = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.question_id);
            questionText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.question_text);
            Log.e("FindViewById", "Working");
        }
    }
}
```

`MyData` class has two fields of type string and their getter/setter methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < questions.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject obj = questions.getJSONObject(i);
                                MyData data = new MyData(
                                        obj.getString("question_id"),
                                        obj.getString("question_text"));
                                Log.e("Question" + " " + i,
                                        "\nQuestion id = " + data.getQuestionId() +
                                                " Question text = " + data.getQuestionText());
                                dataList.add(data);
                            }
// notify data set change call missing
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: or any of the appropriate notify methods https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html

Comment: @Such Thanks you saved my day. Just curious whey recyclerView do work without this method if we load dummy values?

Comment: Just a little dump mistake made my day hard. oh

Comment: @InzimamTariqIT "Just curious whey recyclerView do work without this method"- no it will not work. Either you should give dataList with size more than zero (all the item in list will be shown) or do any add, remove, update operations on the list and call  "notifyDataSetChanged" method to reflect the data items

Comment: @Sush well I'm wondering it was just find in my case. I did nothing but my `loadDummyData();` work well without and data change call in the above code.

Comment: Yes.. Bcz locally data got loaded. Where as network call took time. Network call was asynchrony